# this.field syntactic sugar on constructor parameter list and inherited field.

Tags: oop, dart

Please consider following example that works totally fine:

```dart
abstract class Parent {
  String parentField;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  String childField;

  Child(parentField, childField){
    this.parentField = parentField;
    this.childField = childField;
  }
}
```

When i try to change child constructor to:

```dart
Child(this.parentField, this.childField);
```

I get:

```
error: line X pos Y: unresolved reference to instance field 'parentField' Child(this.parentField, this.childField);
```

My question is:

Is this a design decision? bug? or missing feature worth requesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. From the [Generative Constructors section of the Dart spec.](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.500yt9xvog42):

> An *initializing formal* has the form `this.id`. It is a compile-time error if id is not the name of an instance variable of the immediately enclosing class.

Comment: ok. If it is documented then it is a feature :) Do you think it is so on purpose? Would it be worth to create a feature request on https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/entry for this?

Comment: You can ask and post a link to the created issue in a following comment.

Comment: @fsw Object construction has to be done in a clearly defined order. You can't assign a little here and a little there. In very simple use cases this might work but the rules must hold for more complex configurations too.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am not sure if I am getting your point. I can access this.parentField and set it from constructor body anyways and as far as i get it initializing formals are just syntactic sugar. Do you think the working example I gave is bad design (ignoring the fact that it is trivial)? Also please note Parent is abstract and i don't want it to have a constructor.

Comment: `this.xxx` has special functionality. You can also initialize final fields which you can't in the constructor body. Overloading this syntax with more 'features' would dilute its significance. I think it is important to distinguish this special initialization from general assignment like in the constructor body or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone checking after 2022, this is updated. You can now use,

```
Child(super.parentField, this.childField);
```